# functional way for balancing two vectors in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I would balance two vector representing needs and availability of a product.

This is a canonical problem in Material Requirement Planning very easy in imperative style. Is possible in functional programming ?

I must pass from A1 to A2 with following  priority: assign aval qty first for records with the same :cat , then to needs in early :day.

The format for :day is AAAAMMDD

```
(def A1
  {:avail [{:day 20190101 :qty  10  :mkey "AAABB" :cat "CO1"}
           {:day 20190101 :qty  20  :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}
           {:day 20190102 :qty  50  :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190103 :qty  50  :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190104 :qty  40  :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}]

   :needs [{:day 20190107 :qty -100 :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190108 :qty  -50 :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190109 :qty -100 :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190217 :qty -100 :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}]})


(def A2
  {:avail [{:day 20190101 :qty  0   :mkey "AAABB" :cat "CO1"}
           {:day 20190101 :qty  0   :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}
           {:day 20190102 :qty  0   :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190103 :qty  0   :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190104 :qty  0   :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}]

   :needs [{:day 20190107 :qty 0    :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190108 :qty -10  :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190109 :qty -100 :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}
           {:day 20190217 :qty -70  :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}]})
```

a possible java algorithm for obtaining  A2 from A1

```
ArrayList avail = new ArrayList();
ArrayList needs = new ArrayList();
/* first assign based on same :cat */
for (int i=0;i< needs.size();i++) {
    // get needs record of index i..
    for (int j=0;j< avail.size();j++) {
         // get avail record of index j..
         if (need.cat != avail.cat)  // only same same cat ! 
                continue;
         balance the actuals records needs and avail
         updating relative qty, 
         trying to set need qty to zero decrementing avail
    }
}
/* now again without test on cat */
for (int i=0;i< needs.size();i++) {
    // get needs record of index i..
    for (int j=0;j< avail.size();j++) {
         // get avail record of index j..
         balance the actuals records needs and avail
         updating relative qty 
         trying to set need qty to zero decrementing avail
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give more details around how you want to get from A1 to A2 perhaps using this way of describing each step: "adjust needs of X based on avail of Y because Z...". It might be" a canonical problem in Material Requirement Planning" but I'm not sure how many Clojure programmers are also experts in this domain so making life easier for us should probably help you get an answer faster...  Also I think your date format looks like YYYYMMDD to me.

Comment: Also it's not clear from the problem description *what* the algorithm is doing or *why* needs to be O(n^4). That's going to be prohibitively costly even for relatively trivial datasets.

Comment: You can simply convert the Java code to clojure using `loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do this with two functions:

1. First function is to reduce demands base on one supply
2. Second function uses above function to consume a list of supplies

```clj
(defn consume
  "Reduce demands base on one supply"
  [can-consume? demands supply]
  (reduce (fn [{:keys [supply] :as ans} d]
            (let [qty (:qty supply)]
              (if (can-consume? d supply)
                (let [used (-> d :qty (+ qty))]
                  (-> ans
                      (update :needs conj (assoc d :qty (min 0 used)))
                      (assoc-in [:supply :qty] (max 0 used))))
                (update ans :needs conj d))))
          ;; initial state - no demands just one supply
          {:needs  []
           :supply supply}
          ;; feed demands into reducing function
          demands))

(defn consume-all
  "Reduce demands with a list of supplies"
  [{:keys [needs avails]}]
  (->> (reduce (fn [ans s]
                 (let [{:keys [supply needs]
                        :as   same-cat}      (consume (fn [d s] (and (<= (:day s) (:day d))
                                                                     (= (:cat s) (:cat d))))
                                                      (:needs ans)
                                                      s)
                       {:keys [supply needs]} (if supply ;; supply of same cat is consumed
                                                same-cat
                                                (consume (fn [d s] (<= (:day s) (:day d)))
                                                         (:needs ans)
                                                         s))]
                   (-> ans
                       (assoc :needs needs)
                       (update :avails conj supply))))
               ;; initial state - no supply only demands
               {:needs  needs
                :avails []}
               ;; feed supplies into reducing function
               avails)))
```

Run with your sample

```clj
(consume-all {:needs [{:day 20190107 :qty -100 :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
                       {:day 20190108 :qty -50 :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
                       {:day 20190109 :qty -100 :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}
                       {:day 20190217 :qty -100 :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}]
              :avails  [{:day 20190101 :qty 10 :mkey "AAABB" :cat "CO1"}
                       {:day 20190101 :qty 20 :mkey "OS100" :cat "CO1"}
                       {:day 20190102 :qty 50 :mkey "OS200" :cat "   "}
                       {:day 20190103 :qty 50 :mkey "OS300" :cat "   "}
                       {:day 20190104 :qty 40 :mkey "OS400" :cat "   "}]})

==>
{:needs
 [{:day 20190107, :qty 0, :mkey "OS200", :cat "   "}
  {:day 20190108, :qty -10, :mkey "OS300", :cat "   "}
  {:day 20190109, :qty -100, :mkey "OS400", :cat "   "}
  {:day 20190217, :qty -70, :mkey "OS100", :cat "CO1"}],
 :avails
 [{:day 20190101, :qty 0, :mkey "AAABB", :cat "CO1"}
  {:day 20190101, :qty 0, :mkey "OS100", :cat "CO1"}
  {:day 20190102, :qty 0, :mkey "OS200", :cat "   "}
  {:day 20190103, :qty 0, :mkey "OS300", :cat "   "}
  {:day 20190104, :qty 0, :mkey "OS400", :cat "   "}]}
```

Comment: I programmed imperative all my life, but if is possible doing such things functionally i would become functionally. I will pass some time studying your beautiful code.